# baloorunner crash

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5

In Kubuntu 19.04 baloonrunner crash everytime that I use it.
I paste the error :

```
Application: baloorunner (baloorunner), signal: Segmentation fault
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f7cd7189800 (LWP 15872))]

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f7ccffff700 (LWP 15874)):
#0  __libc_enable_asynccancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/cancellation.S:56
#1  0x00007f7cdaefd716 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7f7cc8004e30, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#2  0x00007f7cd9ae7cb6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f7cd9ae7ddc in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f7cdb47e063 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f7cdb4295bb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f7cdb2742c6 in QThread::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007f7cdc35a565 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#8  0x00007f7cdb275612 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007f7cda351182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#10 0x00007f7cdaf09b1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f7cd6168700 (LWP 15873)):
#0  0x00007f7cdaefd729 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7f7cd6167ca8, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f7cd965b917 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#2  0x00007f7cd965d53a in xcb_wait_for_event () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#3  0x00007f7cd6d586a8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007f7cdb275612 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f7cda351182 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:486
#6  0x00007f7cdaf09b1f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f7cd7189800 (LWP 15872)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  __memmove_sse2_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:326
#7  0x00007f7cdb282dc4 in QByteArray::QByteArray(char const*, int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f7cdac4635f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5BalooEngine.so.5
#9  0x00007f7cdac46431 in Baloo::PostingDB::iter(QByteArray const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5BalooEngine.so.5
#10 0x00007f7cdac4d560 in Baloo::Transaction::postingIterator(Baloo::EngineQuery const&) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5BalooEngine.so.5
#11 0x00007f7cdc54e5ce in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Baloo.so.5
#12 0x00007f7cdc54e39d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Baloo.so.5
#13 0x00007f7cdc54f468 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Baloo.so.5
#14 0x00007f7cdc53dfc0 in Baloo::Query::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Baloo.so.5
#15 0x0000557a09b6b92a in ?? ()
#16 0x0000557a09b6cf16 in ?? ()
#17 0x00007f7cdb454563 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#18 0x00007f7cdb4600c7 in QTimer::timeout(QTimer::QPrivateSignal) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#19 0x00007f7cdb454c5b in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#20 0x00007f7cdbe42551 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#21 0x00007f7cdbe49930 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#22 0x00007f7cdb42a8e9 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#23 0x00007f7cdb47d453 in QTimerInfoList::activateTimers() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#24 0x00007f7cdb47dca4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#25 0x00007f7cd9ae7aae in g_main_context_dispatch () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#26 0x00007f7cd9ae7d48 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#27 0x00007f7cd9ae7ddc in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#28 0x00007f7cdb47e047 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#29 0x00007f7cdb4295bb in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#30 0x00007f7cdb4315e2 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#31 0x0000557a09b6992f in ?? ()
#32 0x00007f7cdae12b6b in __libc_start_main (main=0x557a09b698c0, argc=1, argv=0x7ffe9a9cce18, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffe9a9cce08) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#33 0x0000557a09b699aa in _start ()
[Inferior 1 (process 15872) detached]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same issue in debian testing and found this bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/baloo-kf5/+bug/1828556

So I removed everything using

```bsh
balooctl suspend
balooctl disable
balooctl purge
balooctl enable
balooctl resume
```

And waited a bit until everything was indexed again (I only index the directories where I save documents, so it is pretty fast)

After rebooting the search works fine again. (I guess one update changed the format in an incompatible way)