# KDE 5, baloorunner crash

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, qt, kde5

I am really not sure if this is the best place to ask this question, but baloorunner is crashing constantly every time and there is no address to report this bug.

The question is where is the best place to report such problems ? and how do I mitigate this issue ?

This is the OS:
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-80-generic
OS Type: 64-bit

This is the error report:

```
Application: baloorunner (baloorunner), signal: Bus error
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f9daaa6cc80 (LWP 11021))]

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f9da3fff700 (LWP 11023)):
#0  0x00007f9dae3c4aff in __GI___poll (fds=0x7f9d9c0029e0, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f9daced036e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f9daced04a3 in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f9dae961583 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007f9dae9084db in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f9dae740785 in QThread::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f9daf225efa in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#7  0x00007f9dae7419d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f9dad785609 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:477
#9  0x00007f9dae3d1293 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f9da9ba3700 (LWP 11022)):
#0  0x00007f9dae3c4aff in __GI___poll (fds=0x7f9da9ba2ca8, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f9daca18c1a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#2  0x00007f9daca1a90a in xcb_wait_for_event () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#3  0x00007f9daa3ae298 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007f9dae7419d2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f9dad785609 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:477
#6  0x00007f9dae3d1293 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f9daaa6cc80 (LWP 11021)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  0x00007f9dacd0fafa in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so.0
#7  0x00007f9dacd12e80 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so.0
#8  0x00007f9dacd13165 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so.0
#9  0x00007f9dacd13892 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so.0
#10 0x00007f9dacd13ed4 in mdb_get () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so.0
#11 0x00007f9dae0e253d in Baloo::PostingDB::iter(QByteArray const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5BalooEngine.so.5
#12 0x00007f9dae0ea938 in Baloo::Transaction::postingIterator(Baloo::EngineQuery const&) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5BalooEngine.so.5
#13 0x00007f9daface2c8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Baloo.so.5
#14 0x00007f9dafacd548 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Baloo.so.5
#15 0x00007f9daface660 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Baloo.so.5
#16 0x00007f9dafabb1c0 in Baloo::Query::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Baloo.so.5
#17 0x000055f25580213b in ?? ()
#18 0x000055f2558039f7 in ?? ()
#19 0x00007f9dae935458 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#20 0x00007f9dae94251e in QTimer::timeout(QTimer::QPrivateSignal) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#21 0x00007f9dae935cf5 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#22 0x00007f9daf414a66 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#23 0x00007f9daf41e0f0 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#24 0x00007f9dae90993a in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#25 0x00007f9dae9608b0 in QTimerInfoList::activateTimers() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#26 0x00007f9dae96119c in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#27 0x00007f9daced017d in g_main_context_dispatch () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#28 0x00007f9daced0400 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#29 0x00007f9daced04a3 in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#30 0x00007f9dae961583 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#31 0x00007f9dae9084db in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#32 0x00007f9dae910246 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#33 0x000055f255800184 in ?? ()
#34 0x00007f9dae2d60b3 in __libc_start_main (main=0x55f255800110, argc=1, argv=0x7ffe57a741a8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffe57a74198) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#35 0x000055f2558001fe in _start ()
[Inferior 1 (process 11021) detached]
```

This error report is probably not useful, but I am not sure how to add more to it. Please let me know if you need any other info.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: FYI:  Bug reports are filed against packages; I had a quick look and didn't find `baloorunner` so have no idea what package its found in, nor where it's from. The package & where it's from are necessary for exact details on filing the bug so I'll use this as example link - https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/baloo-kf5 (alas no `baloorunner` file inside) which shows details on exiting bug reports, and where it's maintained. Best reports will be on current version (ie. that currently existing in *jammy* as if it exists there; that'll be easiest & fastest to fix)

Comment: Maybe helpful or worth a look - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138705/baloorunner-crash